# const variable in function assigned at run-time

Tags: c++, function, constants

I recently realized I have the following in my C++ code, and it compiles and runs without any problems.

```
void MyClass::foo(int a) {
    const double x = a;
    ...
    //do stuff with x
    ...
}
```

My question: I thought const variables were assigned a value at compile time and this would have given me a compile error, though in this case it obviously is assigned at runtime. Is the const specifier here being ignored? Or is there something else more complicated going on? Should I remove the const specifier?

Comment: This is just the initialization - which of course you need. You will not be able to change x after the declaration Keep the const!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Constant variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) are assigned a value when initialized (at run-time), and cannot be modified afterwards. References and pointers to constant variables can only be used to read from those variables, the underlying variable being constant or not.

> I thought const variables were assigned a value at compile time

What you are describing are C++11 [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) variables.

> Should I remove the const specifier?

No. You should make everything `const` unless you specifically need it to not be `const`.

Comment: Ah I wasn't aware of the const/constexpr differences. Thanks!